# Remove BOTH ssh key for IP and ssh key for FQDN from known_hosts

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen, known-hosts

Is it possible to remove an ssh key from `known_hosts` both for the IP and for the FQDN of a machine, knowing only one of the 2?

For example, I am on machine A, and I want to remove the public ssh key of machine B (whose IP is 1.2.3.4) from A's `known_hosts`.

If I just do `ssh-keygen -R 1.2.3.4`, I will remove the ssh key for IP 1.2.3.4 from `known_hosts`. But if `known_hosts` also has the ssh key for B's FQDN (say, it's `my.machine.b.com`), then that one won't disappear (without me having to `ssh-keygen -R my.machine.b.com`).

Is it possible to purge `known_hosts` from anything regarding machine B completely, just by knowing B's IP or B's FQDN?

Comment: You know the host key!

Comment: Sorry, my question is probably unclear. I am asking for X, where X is a command or series of command to which I can give B's IP or B's hostname as input (just one of the two), and whose outcome is the removal of all B's pub keys from A's known_hosts. Something like an ssh-keygen -R that takes the IP but also finds and removes references to the hostname, or viceversa.

Comment: Did you find a way?